# How to say "Several times but each on different day" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

English version:

> The teacher scolded Nakamura kun several times but each on different day.

More precisely, for example, Nakamura kun got scolded on Sunday once, on Wednesday once, and on Friday once.

Japanese version (incomplete):

> 先生は中村君を叱った。

How to say the phrase "several times but each on different day"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you need is a math problem language:

> 先生は中村君を [A] 、それぞれ（異なる／別の）日に叱った。

While in [A] you could use:

- 数回
- 何回か
- 数度
- 何度か

Answer (score 0):

You can render "each on different day" as それぞれ別の日に but it's still ambiguous if it's several times a day, so I'd say 先生は中村くんを 日を分けて 何度か叱った。